# Restricting number of characters in a message in JTextPane

Tags: java

I have a JTextPane where I want to restrict the user to enter a message with only 200 characters. So, I have a KeyListener which listens for a Keyevent and checks for a KeyEvent. If the message is more than 200 characters, a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog is shown to display a warning to the user. This bit works fine.

The problem is that once the warning is displayed and the users clicks on 'OK' he can only use the Backspace key in the JTextPane. I want the user to be able to use the delete key, the arrow keys, the shift and control keys to be able to select the text to be deleted.

Can anybody suggest a way of achieving this??

```
// Add Key Listener to Send Field
chatEditorKeyListener = new KeyAdapter() 
{
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
   {
       checkKeystroke(e);
   }
};



private void checkKeystroke(KeyEvent e) 
{
   //Check if enter or back space is entered
   if( e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ) 
   {
      // user is typing, so test the size as we go and report when we hit boundary
      String text = messageBox.getText();
      if(text.length() > maxMessageSize)
      {
         showAlertBox();
      }
   }
   else if ( e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
   {
       //User sending the message
       e.consume();
       String text = messageBox.getText();
       if(text.length() > maxMessageSize)
       {
           showAlertBox();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section from the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) on "Text Component Features" which contains a section on "Implementing a Document Filter" that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Drag-and-drop. Copy-and-paste. Accessibility input methods. There are many reasons why this approach is not appropriate.

Instead restrict the contents through the `Document`. Set a `DocumentFilter` through `AbstractDocument.setDocumentFilter` so that you do not need to subclass or implement the document.

A pop up is not great for user experience. Be more subtle. Not allowing any more character will do (please don't beep!). Possibly add a countdown as twitter and stackoverflow do.

Answer (score 0):

Test if the current size+1 hits the boundary, consume the event and show the message box.
It's important to comsume the event to never actually oversize your text box!